iterate over rows in a form
basically i want to write a code that iterates through each row in this form and echoes it, but currently when i hit "save" it only echoes the bottom row there.screenshot

$id=$_POST['id'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$JobNumber=htmlspecialchars($_POST['JobNumber']);
$jobName=htmlspecialchars($_POST['jobName']);
$jobAddress=htmlspecialchars($_POST['jobAddress']);
$MatDesc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['MatDesc']);
$Contact=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Contact']);
$ContactNo=$_POST['ContactNo'];
$MatListLoc=htmlspecialchars($_POST['MatListLoc']);
$Driver=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Driver']);
$jobStatus=htmlspecialchars($_POST['jobStatus']);
/*
$database = new database();
//$id=1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobmat.details where relatedID=:id"; // Update this query according to your table name
$database->query($sql);
$database->bind(":id", $id);
$database->execute();
$rows = $database->object();
*/


//$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Fetch rows as an associative array
//while ($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {echo $row."<br/>";}

foreach($_POST as $daa){echo $daa ."<br/>";}

i have tried the foreach loop and it should be echoeing both rows, but currently it's only echoing the second row.

The inputs should use names like name="jobName[]. Then $_POST['jobName'] will be an array, and you can iterate over it.
